# laravel default wildcasting route shielding route registered by SomeServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have following route definition in my `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/captcha','Api\MyCaptchaController@captcha'); // this will return a service entry url: /captcha/default
Route::get('/{cslug1}/{cslug2}','Front\FrontController@default_index');
```

and in the `CaptachaServiceProvider` `boot()` method, we defined the `/captcha/default` route:

```
$this->app['router']->get('captcha/default', '\Mews\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptcha')
```

and above `route` the action which will serve `/captcha/default` url request.
The issue is: When  above url request is lauched by browser, the default wildcast route entity is hit.(`/{cslug1}/{cslug2}`)
How to make sure the `captcha/default` is served by `CaptchaController` instead of `FrontController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel will match the first route it finds. So if `/{cslug1}/{cslug2}` is registered with the router *before* your `captcha/default` route, then that will be invoked and the router will stop looking for any other matches.

Instead, you’ll need to make sure your wildcard route is registered after *all* other routes. You can do this by putting it in its own service provider and making sure it’s the last one registered in your **config/app** file:

```php
protected $providers = [
    // All other providers...

    // Add service provider here that registers /{cslug1}/{cslug2} route
];
```

Comment: It is a reasonable explaination. But i do not want to move the /{cslug1}/{cslug2} route to Service provider. Instead, I'd like to make sure the CaptachaServiceProvider will register the route before /{cslug1}/{cslug2} which defined the web.php, is that possible? i have upvoted your proposal, although, i am not willing to accept your answer now

Comment: _But i do not want to move the /{cslug1}/{cslug2} route to Service provider._ Like I say, routes are matched in the order they’re registered, so if you want your fallback route to be ran last, you need to register it last.

Comment: when the routes defined in web.php will be populated? Is it possible to bring `MyCaptachaServiceProvider` ahead of consuming routes in web.php(and populating the whole routes)?

Comment: They’re loaded by the `RouteServiceProvider` funnily enough.

Answer (score 0):

Define your `FrontController` route to ignore requests if first parameter is `captcha`:

```
Route::get('/{cslug1}/{cslug2}','Front\FrontController@default_index')
           ->where('cslug1', '^((?!captcha).)*$');
```

Comment: your propsosal works, but is not the best approach, thanks for your feedback